# Don't find kafka StoreBuilder class

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka 0.11. I don't find StoreBuilder class in the kafka-streams-0.11.0.0.jar.
Any idea what's the issue?

[image: Please refer the attached screenshot]

Comment: Not clear why you are expecting it to be there at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class was added in Kafka `1.0.0` - [KAFKA-5650](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5650)

Luckily, newer Kafka Streams libraries are backwards compatible with 0.11.0 brokers (assuming that's why you picked that version)

I notice your class name is "test jdbc", though, so I would suggest using the existing Kafka Connect JDBC product rather than beginning to reinvent it

> I wanted to transform the incoming stream data using kstream.transform() function and then feed the transformed data to Oracle db table VIA JdbcSinkConnector

You might want to try making or using a [Simple Message Transform (SMT)](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms) instead. Let the JdbcSink connector handle getting the records out of Kafka for you, and the property configuration for the Connector is in a separate location, and re-usable, rather than specific to your code.

The [Transformation](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.0/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.java) interface has one `apply()` method that you can convert a message however you want, which effectively is the same concept as `kstream.map(...).to("topic")`, but the destination is not a separate Kafka topic

Comment: thanks for your response. I wanted to transform the incoming stream data using kstream.transform() function and then feed the transformed data to Oracle db table VIA JdbcSinkConnector. Is there any sample code/link available using newer Kafka Streams libraries to do transformation?

Comment: The library didn't change completely, only classes are added, modified. Whatever examples you currently have should still work. Especially those using the StateStoreBuilder

Comment: Can you please do let me know Which version of kafka OR kafka streams do I need to use?

Comment: sorry, what i mean is: I don't want to go for backwards compatible with 0.11.0 brokers. If that's the case, which version of kafka OR kafka streams do I need to use?

Comment: You can use any version newer than `0.10.2`, but what version of Kafka **are** you running? The newest version is `2.0`... And to get the class in your Kafka Streams code, you can run any broker version, you only need to update your JARs in the application. I'm not sure I understand your concerns

Comment: I am using kafka 0.11.0.0. Thanks a lot for all the information. I will get back to you in case if I face any issues.